# jSecurity JDBCRealm SQL setup

Tags: java, sql, security, jdbc, jsecurity

I am trying to use jSecurity for an enterprise java app, but the documentation is...well...lacking.

Has anyone out there in SO-land been able to get the JDBCRealm setup, and if so did you find a SQL setup script or did you just derive it on your own? Either way, can you provide the create SQL statements to make this work?

I have posted to the mailing list [here](http://www.jsecurity.org/node/1075), but I don't know if\when I will get a response\I don't have a long time to wait.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can tell, this is it (or will work well enough in most circumstances):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users](
    [username] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user_roles](
    [username] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [role_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[roles_permissions](
    [role_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [permission] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

[EDIT: If you are using Maven you will need ehcache and commons-logging in your POM as well]